# vs2012 changed the default association of EXE files to notepad

Tags: windows

**EDIT**: using the "change user" login screen, when reloging into the account, all icons are restored ok. So it seems the question is closed.

using the "view" menu item in the TFS dialog box to open an exe file (in TFS) i forgot to uncheck the "always open with" checkbox.

Now in Windows all .exe files are associated with the program i choose (notepad), and all icons of program files are the icon of notepad.

I managed to revert the default "open" action on .exe files so i can now run any program without opening notepad.

But i'm stuck with the notepad icons displayed on all my programs. I've deleted the iconcache.db file, and run a .reg file to "restore" default associations of EXE files in Windows 7. Rebooted. Nothing happens, notepad icon stays everywhere.

What registry key should i delete in my profile to get back the original icons for all .EXE files ?

Comment: I trust that Visual Studio 2012 did not change EXE default association to NotePad. Normally virus / trojan does the job.

Comment: No, the association was changed because of me, using VS2012. I can post screen shots of how to reproduce the problem. There is a missing guard against this unwanted change in VS TFS View dialog for exe files that are in TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this REG file and import it, assuming yours is still using the default registry path. May need administrator account.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\DefaultIcon]
@="%1"
```

Comment: This registry value is already set to %1. I think it is somewhere in the current profile registry hive (HKU).

Comment: Can you post the exported registry of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile` to a code snippetting website (I forgot its URL)?